# Dialogflow app stops working when starting the Sign-In flow on Actions on Google

Tags: google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm trying to sign in a user with Account link Google Signin over the assistant.

So I've created an intent in Dialogflow and called it "Start Signin", triggered by the phrase "signin".
Then I've enabled webhook call for this intent, and created this fulfillment:

```
app.intent("Start Signin", conv => {
  conv.ask(new SignIn());
});
```

I've also enabled account linking on Actions on Google.

When simulating the app and providing the input phrase "signin", after a couple of seconds I get the response "We're sorry, but something went wrong. Please try again."

When checking the Cloud functions logs, I can see that "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment" runs not once, but multiple times always finishing with status code 200.

This is my full index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {dialogflow, SignIn} = require("actions-on-google");

const app = dialogflow({
  clientId: "notimportantforstackoverflow"
});

app.intent("Start Signin", conv => {
  conv.ask(new SignIn());
});

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you need to create an intent with actions_intent_SIGN_IN. Your action tries to sign in but goes nowhere when it is completed.

For more information, you can visit https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in